# setting cookie in Chrome, just providing value and expires value, NOT getting set

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

```
document.cookie = "favoriteCar=honda; expires=" + expireDate.toString();
```

where expireDate is a new Date() plus 1 day.  So it ends up being...

```
favoriteCar=honda; expires=Thur, 29 Dec 2011 14:22:23 GMT
```

After I set this, and do `alert(document.cookie)`, it just alerts blank.

This is in Chrome.  What am I missing?  I don't want to have to set any more parameters; I want Chrome to set this automatically without having to figure out what the current domain or path is.  This is being used for a plugin that sets localStorage with a cookie fallback option.

Thanks!

Comment: try changing `expireDate.toString()` to `expireDate.toGMTString()` and see if that works.

Comment: that did work!  altho, I'm doing toUTCString() just in case the user is not in GMT time zone.  thanks!

Comment: if you put that as an answer, I'll mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `expireDate.toString()` to `expireDate.toGMTString()` or `toUTCString()`.

The issue is that `toString` produces a different date format that is not compatible with the cookie spec.